# Using pyEphem to calculate moon phase for a certain location: cannot get it to work correctly

Tags: python, pyephem

I would like to know the moon phase at a certain location at a certain date. For example, let's take Makassar in Indonesia, on the 27 August 2018.

I have the following script, from [this page](https://keithmfoster.com/calculating-the-moons-phases-with-two-python-methods/):

```
import ephem

# Define the observer's location
observer = ephem.Observer()
observer.lat = '-5.156276'
observer.long = '119.434574 '
    
# Define the date
observer.date = '2018/08/27'
 
# Define the moon
moon = ephem.Moon()
 
# Calculate the phase of the moon
moon.compute(observer)
 
# Print the phase of the moon
print(moon.moon_phase)
```

I get the result: 0.9968778436943431
which corresponds to very close to a new moon. But when I look it up on the web, the [moon at this time in this location was a full moon](https://phasesmoon.com/indonesia/makassar/moonday27August2018.html). So I was expecting something close to 0.5.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The pyephem documentation says that `moon_phase` is a percentage of surface illuminated - so 0.99 is indeed a full moon.  (This seems like a strange choice of representation, since it cannot distinguish between waxing & waning phases.)